# How to group by category and then count the frequency of words using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, nltk

my `df` looks like this:

```
category       text
--------       ----
soccer         soccer game is good
soccer         soccer game
basketball     game basketball
basketball     game
volleyball     sport volleyball sport
```

What I want to do is `groupby` `category` and then list the `words` by its `frequency`

```
category       text          frequency
--------       ----          ---------
soccer         soccer        2
               game          2 
               is            1
               good          1
basketball     game          2
               basketball    1  
volleyball     sport         2
               volleyball    1
```

what did I do?

- I group all the `text` together

`df.groupby(['category])['text'].sum()`

Now all the text are on the same `rows` since I grouped it but I do not know how to do a Frequency Table using each word count.

Could someone please help me?

Comment: You could use `split` and `explode()` to get the individual words into individual rows, then groupby with `count`

Answer (score 3):

**#Method 1:**

You can use `series.str.split` with `explode` and the `groupby.value_counts`

```
(df.assign(text=df['text'].str.split()).explode("text")
 .groupby("category",sort=False)['text'].value_counts())
```

---

```
category    text      
soccer      game          2
            soccer        2
            good          1
            is            1
basketball  game          2
            basketball    1
volleyball  sport         2
            volleyball    1
Name: text, dtype: int64
```

**#Method 2:**

For older version of pandas using `np.concatenate` and `index.repeat` with `df.join` (There are other methods listed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53218931/how-to-unnest-explode-a-column-in-a-pandas-dataframe))

```
s = df['text'].str.split()
(df[['category']].join(pd.Series(np.concatenate(s),
                      index=df.index.repeat(s.str.len()),name='text'))
.groupby("category",sort=False)['text'].value_counts())
```

**#Method 3:** using `MultiLabelBinarizer` from `sklearn`

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import MultiLabelBinarizer

s = df['text'].str.split()
mlb = MultiLabelBinarizer()
mlb.fit(s)
out = pd.DataFrame(mlb.transform(s),columns=mlb.classes_).groupby(df['category']).sum()
out.replace(0,np.nan).stack().astype(int)

category              
basketball  basketball    1
            game          2
soccer      game          2
            good          1
            is            1
            soccer        2
volleyball  sport         1
            volleyball    1
dtype: int32
```

Comment: thanks for composing the answer. I am getting this error `'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'explode'`

Comment: I am locked on the version number. possible to do it via `NLTK`?

Comment: I get the following error with the updated code: `ValueError: zero-dimensional arrays cannot be concatenated`

Comment: @floss i just tested with the df in the question and it worked. did you check with the example df you posted?

Comment: @floss added another way. Please try. All of these are tested on the above df in the question and they work for me.

Answer (score 0):

[value_counts](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html)
is the right way. Usable inside a groupby too after split in words